# Small security enclosures

Tags: case, security, enclosure

I work in a co-working space and keep a small NAS, a micro-PC, a router and a few other small components running on my desk. While it's a safe space I'd like to add a bit more anti-theft security. Because they're all small components I didn't want to go through the hassle of trying to cable them all down individually (my NAS could just be unscrewed and the hard drives removed anyway), I had the idea of finding a metal enclosure I could put on the floor, shove all the devices inside and just lock the box to my desk.

I've not been able to find much like this though, closest is a server rack enclosure (http://www.amazon.ca/Tripp-Lite-SRW12US-Enclosure-Cabinet/dp/B001TGUYI2/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1450206234&sr=8-8&keywords=server+enclosure) but that seems overkill, don't need the wall mounting or the size.

Anyone aware of any other solutions for this sort of thing? Or at least a rack enclosure that's smaller than usual? As long as it's lockable, somewhat ventilated and has a a space for cables to come out, I'm good. Min volume ~30cm^3, max ~50cm^3, shape doesn't much matter, just going under the desk.

Thanks!

Comment: Any specific dimensions you're looking for? Or at least any maximum or minimum dimensions?